# Batch being blocked by a trigger

Tags: trigger, batch, class

I have a trigger that prevents update of a specific field. At the same time I have a batch that is supposed to update that field. How do I make the trigger allow the batch to run its job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[System](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm) contains a method called `isBatch()`. You can use this to disable the trigger for all batches:

```
if (!system.isBatch()) // validate records
```

If you want to disable it for this specific batch only, you can use static flags. Here some sort of handler pattern greatly facilitates this change.

```
public with sharing class LeadTriggerHandler()
{
    public static Boolean validateSomeField = true;

    //...
        if (validateSomeField) // do stuff
}
```

Then from your batch, you would just turn the validation off around your operation. Remember to book-end (turn it back on afterward).

```
public with sharing class MyBatch extends Database.Batchable<SObject>
{
    //...
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<SObject> scope)
    {
        LeadTriggerHandler.validateSomeField = false;
        // update records
        LeadTriggerHandler.validateSomeField = true;
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I'm a little confused. Can I do this within the trigger If(system.isBatch() != true) { .. execute code } ?

Comment: @Arthlete Or simpler still, `!system.isBatch()`. I will amend my answer.

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you so much. Can you explain a little more about the second example. I cannot comprehend what you are doing. Where is the system.isBatch() in that example?

Comment: @Arthlete Further amended.

Comment: That's awesome man! Thanks for explaining in detail!